# Return XML from via REST in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to write a php script "test.php" that outputs the contents of a "sample.xml" file (with appropriate Content-Type: xml) just as if a user went directly to the "sample.xml". How do I accomplish this? Is there some framework needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no framework needed... just a little work with [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), here is an example:

**test.php:**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
echo file_get_contents('sample.xml');
?>
```